# CSS in webpack config entry vs importing into JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-4

I've seen many people import their `main.css` file in their `main.js` file, but this feels wrong to me. Why would I want my JavaScript to know or care about the CSS? What's wrong with including it in the webpack configuration entry instead?

Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  entry: {
    main: ['src/main.js', 'src/main.css']
  },

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One great use-case is the usage of [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in order to scope your css and prevent leakage of it.

Whenever you import `css` inside your `js` file, you will get a mapping object between your selectors to the generated unique selectors.

That can be done with [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

Comment: So is it just that some webpack loaders/plugins do not work when the CSS is outside of the JavaScript import?

Comment: you can say it :]

Comment: So is it wrong to put the CSS file in the entry? Or is it just that it CAN be wrong? And is there any documentation stating any of this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, even if you don't need the css module functionality, may be you do want to apply autoprefixer or some othe css manipulation.